Is it possible to show query results in vertical on Google sheet or way to generate them?
I try
=QUERY(Kid," select A where B=2") 

on the top cell and
=QUERY(Kid," select B where B=2 ") 

on the bottom cell but the top cell said Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data.


try:
=TOCOL(QUERY(Kid, "select A,B where B=2", 1),,1)




You may try with vstack():
=vstack(
query(Kid," select A where B=2"),
query(Kid," select B where B=2 ")
)

OR
={
    query(Kid," select A where B=2");
    query(Kid," select B where B=2 ")
  }

